# How to Interpolate very large datasets in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, point, interpolation

I am working with a very large set of point data, (XYAttribute) which I wish to display as a raster.

I've been using Interpolate, this is successful but very slow.

I have other programmes that simply display the data according to a colourbar, is there a faster/less data intensive means of converting my dataset to a raster?

Comment: Have you tried _Raster_ > _Conversion_ > _Rasterize_?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it sounds much better. I'll give it a go when QGIS lets me back in.

Comment: Not sure why but this seems to be failing. I spotted a suggestion elsewhere on Stack Exchange that I have to start out with an image file, the Rasterize tool being unable to create it's own?

Comment: I only used it a couple of times but yes, I think you will have to create a blank image file first.